# Leaving US with a good record

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals

Recently, I had my asylum court hearing and I was refused asylum status. My attorney recommended appealing but I want something concrete i.e. papers and future. Appealing unfortunately would give me small percentage to actually get something in the future. My plan is to move to Europe(Ireland/Poland) where my boyfriend resides to study Computer Science, however I’m not sure if my current case can have any negative impact on the student visa process. I was told that even if I voluntary leave before appeal deadline the deportation order would be filled anyway, meaning that I will have a bad record.

I found something on the internet regarding voluntary leaving but when asked about it in the office I was told that nothing can be done [[link to article]](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/voluntary-departure-who-is-eligible.html).

It is worth mentioning that I meet all requirements. Now I’m having thoughts that they don’t want to actually help me with anything besides appealing which would give them a nice profit. Is there something I could do in this case?

The lawyer also said that there’s a possibility that the case filed against me from the DHS could be withdrawn which I will be notified in a week time. All I want to do is leave on good terms which impossible right now.

PS. We know that the easiest way would be to get married but I don’t want to rush things up just to get papers, although this might be the only way in.

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t think strangers on the internet will be able to give you better advice than your immigration attorney. Given the complexities of your case, you’d be wise to heed their advice.

Comment: @RoboKaren I totally agree, the only problem is that they're not giving any advice. For past two weeks I was promised to receive some kind of information but since then they're only postponing it, yet the time is running out.

Comment: In general, if you intend to end up settled in the US, or possibly even visit the US again, you should not leave the US without a lawyer's advice. Doing so could cause a variety of problems. If you disbelieve what your lawyer is saying, you should have a consultation with another lawyer. Though if you came to the US requesting asylum it's probably true. The US is one of the worst places to try to seek refuge/asylum, and it's only gotten worse over the last few years.

Comment: " the case filed against me from the DHS". What do you mean by that? Do you just mean a deportation order? Have you actually received a deportation order?

Comment: @DJClayworth No, I haven't received a deportation order. My attorney needs to "convince" the DHS attorney that I would leave the US and I don't want to pursue an appealing, which would help me leave without a deportation order.

Answer (score 3):

Any fresh visa application will look at your **current** situation and if you appear likely to leave again when your stay is up. An unsuccessful asylum application makes that difficult, and so does your unsettled residency status.